# Why is my model pinching?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

My model is pinching at this particular section. I have done some cloth sculpting on it and now it has this weird pinch that does not exist when in edit mode. When I try to sculpt it out, it negatively affects my object in edit mode creating a weird lump with a sharp ridge. Any help appreciated!

My .blend file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M7OYEXWOggk-VDig1yjogykV4Vtc9w0X/view?usp=drive_link

[image]

Comment: Hello, what pinching are you talking about? Deactivate the Armature modifier and you'll see that there's no difference between Object and Edit mode, what happens is probably that when you move your mesh with the armature it gets deformed on some parts

Comment: That mesh also has all the normals inverted but I don't know whether that's what's causing the problem as I can't seem to flip them.